# strange exception on named parameter for native query in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a query

```
select ... from x join y on ..
where ... and :age between y.min and y.max
```

But when executing the query with hibernate i receive

> org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [age]

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you post the actual query?

Comment: The full query as well, along with the annotation you're using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't posted the actual query, my inference from your snippet is that you have the :age parameter in the wrong place in the query. The syntax for a query's where clause is `column_name operator value` so what you should have in place of `:age` is the actual column name of one of your tables. What you are probably trying to do is `y.min >= :age and y.max <=:age`.

Comment: age is not a parameter. And the query works well when i put age (12 for example) manually, not as named parameter.

Comment: Do you know that `where 1=1` is valid in sql? And if age is not a parameter, why does it have a : in front?

Comment: Ah okey. Now i understand. It's not by chance named "named **parameter**". So **:value** should be value of some parameter. Right?

Comment: so the solution is y.min >= :age and y.max <=age ?

Comment: close. `y.min >= :age and y.max <=:age` would probably do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

check your java code if you have passed "age" properly. Possibly you might have missed it, or maybe misspelled it.

It will be good if you share you java side code also.